# How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the HTML using angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have successfully done code to display a PDF file in HTML using angular instead of the "Open/Save" dialog. Now, I'm stuck trying to display a Word document. I used  to display a Word document and done successfully but i want to restrict the file to be opened in new tab so that he can't download

Answer (score 1):

Unlike PDF, Word documents can't be opened directly in the browser, but if you want to display a word document in a web page and secure it (prevent users from downloading it) you can use Either Google Docs/Office 360 Viewer

Embed them a new page and write some JS to further secure it by disabling copy/paste & right-click (but please note that this JS might get disabled) using Iframe like this

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://ieee802.org/secmail/docIZSEwEqHFr.doc&embedded=true" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Examples:

[Google Docs Viewer](https://jsfiddle.net/7xr419yb/embedded/result/)

[Microsoft Office Viewer](https://jsfiddle.net/gcuzq343/embedded/result/)

Comment: But how will we use this if we have base64 for docx file